# How to create a shadow stack using modify_ldt() and segment registers like fs/gs

Tags: c, linux, assembly, x86, system-calls

In [Control Flow Integrity](http://research.microsoft.com/pubs/64250/ccs05.pdf) (CCS 2005), a *protected shadow call stack* is maintained in an isolated x86 segment. Specifically, they use `gs` to point to the memory segment. But I don't know how to create this isolated memory segment in user-mode application code. AFAIK, `modify_ldt` creates a custom LDT entry. Will it help? I found few examples on how to use this system call except for the description on Linux manual page. Could anyone give me a detailed sample code? Thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: That link didn't work for me.  "An error occurred while processing your request.
Reference #50.477dedad.1458446445.c00e0e1"

Comment: What your saying doesn't make a lot of sense. The instructions CALL and RET are hardwired to use the stack pointed by SS:ESP, you can't redirect it to GS or anywhere else. You can create a call stack somewhere else manually but there's no obvious advantage for using GS to do this.

Comment: @RossRidge I have corrected the link. They instrument the program to save the return address to the shadow call stack pointed by `gs`

Comment: Yah, like I said it doesn't make sense. They're using `gs:[0]` as a stack pointer, but they could just as easily use `ds:[stack_ptr]` or `fs:[tls_stack_ptr]`. Anyways that's not the hard part, the hard part is instrumenting the code, ie. change it so it manually uses the alternate stack. Do you know how you're going to do that?

Comment: They use `gs` to hide the segment they create. Will `ds:[stack_ptr]` achieve the same goal? They used `vulcan`-- a Microsoft proprietary to do instrumentation. But I am going to instrument during compilation by modifying the LLVM backend. But firstly I have to know how to create a isolated segment in user-mode program. Will `modify_ldt` help?

Comment: It doesn't hide the stack at all. It's still accessible somewhere through `ds`. Providing a reference to it through `gs` only makes it easier to find. And no, firstly you need to be able to instrument the code. Once you've done that you can worry about where you're going to place this second code stack. And once you've done that, if you do end up deciding creating a selector to reference it is the best idea, then yes, you can use `modify_ldt` to create it.

Comment: I should also add this won't work 64-bit Windows as it doesn't support the LDT.

Comment: @RossRidge: I agree with your comments except for `they could just as easily use ds:[stack_ptr]` - that would not be reentrant.